# How to find multiple maxes in tuple list python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Say I have a list of tuples that contain a name and number

```
[('John', 212), ('Mary', 312), ('Joe', 400) ...]
```

How can I go about fetching the top say 100 out of a list of tuples by comparing the number?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "top" you mean "having the highest value", you could first sort the list, with the key being the second value of the tuple, and then slice only the data you need from the sorted list.

```py
x = [('John', 212), ('Mary', 312), ('Joe', 400) ...]  # Create list
x.sort(key=lambda y: -1*y[1])  # Sort list based on descending value of element at index 1 in each tuple
x[:100]  # Return the first 100 values of the list
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is returning 100 of the same tuple. EDIT: Apologies, I believe this is correct, I think my tuple has a problem with it. Thank you